# What is the best place to close a sqlite3 connection in obj-c?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, sqlite

I'm opening the database connection in AppDelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

and I'm closing on `applicationWillTerminate`

```
- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application
{
    /*
     Called when the application is about to terminate.
     Save data if appropriate.
     See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
     */
    NSLog(@"Closing DB");
    if(database) sqlite3_close(database);
}
```

But when I close (really close) the app on the simulator, I do not get the log "Closing DB" in the console. Is it normal?

What is the best place to close a sqlite3 connection in Objective-c?

(really close means

– Double tap the Home button to bring up the Multitasking bar
– Press and hold anywhere on the multitasking bar until the icons on it start to wiggle.
– While they are wiggling, each icon has a Minus sign symbol above it. 
– Press the Minus symbol above any app to close it down.)

Answer (score 1):

This is because your application didn't terminate. It went into background. Try adding your code to applicationDidEnterBackground

Comment: I followed these steps "– Double tap the Home button to bring up the Multitasking bar
– Press and hold anywhere on the multitasking bar until the icons on it start to wiggle.
– While they are wiggling, each icon has a Minus sign symbol above it. 
– Press the Minus symbol above any app to close it down." Even follow them I didn't see the log output.

Comment: did you try putting the code in applicationDidEnterBackground ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to avoid usage of -`applicationWillTerminate:` method because you have not enough time(!) to do your work correctly - maybe system is rebooting or shutting down. The best practice to save data and purge unused resources (if needed) is to put your code in -`applicationDidEnterBackground:` method.

From Apple's `UIApplicationDelegate` Protocol Reference:

> Your implementation of this method has approximately five seconds to
>   perform any tasks and return. If you need additional time to perform
>   any final tasks, you can request additional execution time from the
>   system by calling beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:. In
>   practice, you should return from applicationDidEnterBackground: as
>   quickly as possible. If the method does not return before time runs
>   out your application is terminated and purged from memory.
>
> You should perform any tasks relating to adjusting your user interface
>   before this method exits but other tasks (such as saving state) should
>   be moved to a concurrent dispatch queue or secondary thread as needed.
>   Because it's likely any background tasks you start in
>   applicationDidEnterBackground: will not run until after that method
>   exits, you should request additional background execution time before
>   starting those tasks. In other words, first call
>   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler: and then run the task on a
>   dispatch queue or secondary thread.

(c) [taken from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7443200/611055)